# How Nodejs knows if sync or async

Tags: node.js

I understand what a callback is and what asynchronous means, what I don't get is how to run asynchronous functions in node.

For example, how is this

```
var action = (function(data,callback) {
    result = data+1;
    callback(result);
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    action(5, function(r){
        res.end(r.toString());
    });
}).listen(80);
```

different from this

```
var action = (function(data) {
    result = data+1;
    return result;
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var r = action(5);
    res.end(r.toString());
}).listen(80);
```

?

I guess in the first example I'm doing it asynchronously, yet I don't know how Node knows when to do it sync or async... is it a matter of the return? or the fact that in the sync mode we're doing `var x = func(data);`?

And also: when to use sync or async? Because obviously you don't want to use it when adding +1... is it OK to use async just when performing IO tasks, such as reading from DB?

For example, I'm using the library crypto to encrypt a short string (50 chars at most), is this case a good example where I should already be using async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess in the first example I'm doing it asynchronously...

Your first example isn't async :) Merely passing a callback and calling it when you're done doesn't make a function asynchronous.

Asynchronous means that, basically, you're telling Node: *"here, do this for me, and let me know when you're done while I continue doing other stuff"*.

Your example is not handing anything to Node for future completion. It's doing a calculation and calling the callback immediately after that. That's functionally the same as your second example, where you *return* the result of the calculation.

However, you can change your first example to something that *is* asynchronous:

```
var action = (function(data,callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result = data + 1;
    callback(result);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here, you're telling Node to delay calling the callback for one second, by using `setTimeout`. In the mean time, Node won't get stuck waiting for a second; it will happily accept more HTTP requests, and each one will be delayed one second before the response is sent.

> When to use sync or async?

Asynchronous code is "viral": if you rely on functions that are async, your own code that uses those functions will also have to be async (generally by accepting a callback, or using another mechanism to deal with asynchronicity, like promises).

> For example, I'm using the library crypto to encrypt a short string (50 chars at most), is this case a good example where I should already be using async?

This depends on which function you're using. AFAIK, most encryption functions in `crypto` aren't asynchronous, so you can't "make" them asynchronous yourself.

Comment: OK, then I completely misunderstood everything... Say I have a function that does several things, and I want it to run 'behind' so that it doesn't block the main loop, and once it is done, I want to run a callback action. Then what should I do? set a timeout with 0ms?

Comment: @CarlosNavarro probably [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg). However, you should be aware that using it won't miraculously make your code _not_ block the event loop. In the end, JS is single-threaded, so it can only "do" one thing at a time.

Comment: @robertklep so there are functions that are asyncronous? If so, how can I make one?

Comment: @alumi the [Eloquent Javascript chapter on Asynchronous Programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) will show you different methods of handling asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples will work synchronous. Simple async operations are **setTimout** and **setInterval**.

Node actually doesn't care what code are you running. You can **block** or not ([blocking/non-blocking](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/blocking-vs-non-blocking.md)).

In other words - you have [event loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_loop.htm). If your process is async he will pass the program control to the event loop, so it can execute any other action node needs to be done. If not - he wont.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a function to work asynchronously, you can do that using promises, look at the code below :

```
function is_asynch(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      resolve( here_your_synch_function() )
})
}
```